# Extract a column from a text file into a list

Tags: python, list

I have a text file which contains a table comprised of numbers e.g:

```
5,10,6
6,20,1
7,30,4
8,40,3
9,23,1
4,13,6
```

if for example I want the numbers contained only in the third column, how do i extract that column into a list?

I have tried the following:

```
myNumbers.append(line.split(',')[2])
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us your code.  This is a very easy task.  Hint: the `csv` module.

Comment: I updated the question with what I have tried, but I do not want to use the csv module.

Comment: What is `line`? Lists are zero-indexed in Python, so "third column" would be `[2]`

Comment: If you aren't using it - [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module would be preferred

Comment: @OneCricketeer He said he doesn't want to use that. Don't know why.

Comment: Don't forget to strip off the newline from `line`. `line.strip().split(',')[2]`

Comment: Why don't you want to use the csv module?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What happened when you tried that? You probably got `IndexError: list index out of range`, right? If so, then I suppose this is a duplicate of [this existing question](/q/1098643/4518341), which I found by googling the error message. If not, then we need more details: please make a [mre] including enough code to reproduce the problem and the full error message. BTW, for more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Curiosity, I'm new to python and I only know how to do things without relying on specific modules. The strip method was what I was looking for.

Comment: The beauty of Python is its extensive standard library.  You NEED to rely on the standard modules.  They are what make Python programming efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The strip method will make sure that the newline character is stripped off. The split method is used here to make sure that the commas are used as a delimiter.

```
line.strip().split(',')[2]
```